# json serialization and deserialization with xamarin App isn't working as expected

Tags: java, c#, json, xamarin

i'm trying to do serialization and deserialization,
but somehow its not working on xamarin app the same as it working with console app,
a quick example using this json string and custom wrapper

```
    public class JsonWrapper
{
    public string ObjType { get; set; }
    public object Obj { get; set; }
}
```

and this is a json direct string to be clear

```
            var json =
            "{\"ObjType\":\"System.Exception\",\"Obj\":{\"ClassName\":\"System.Exception\",\"Message\":\"Printer Is Not Connected\",\"Data\":null,\"InnerException\":null,\"HelpURL\":null,\"StackTraceString\":null,\"RemoteStackTraceString\":null,\"RemoteStackIndex\":0,\"ExceptionMethod\":null,\"HResult\":-2146233088,\"Source\":null,\"WatsonBuckets\":null}}\r\n";
        var obj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonWrapper>(json);

        var type = Type.GetType(obj.ObjType);
        var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj.Obj), type);
        var message = (obj2 as Exception).Message;
```

its gonna get the message variable with missing info, i mean won't get the message which is Printer isn't connected,
the same code working fine with console App so idk,
can someone help?

Comment: Are you claiming JsonConvert works differently on different platforms? If so that is a bug, however more than likely its not a bug and you are doing something differently. Its now up to you to prove its exactly the same

Comment: its exactly the same, i'm trying with direct json string which should work the same @TheGeneral

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your exact same code on *Xamarin Android* compiled using *Level 29, 10.0 (Q) SDK* in the *Main activity*, and it worked fine

**Screen shots**

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: weird, still getting the same  message which is  ""Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown."
even changed the target to the same and everything 
idk

Comment: @Felixanius Try catch the exception, and paste the actual exception message

Comment: its not an exception, the obj2 instance i receive is a like a "New Exception();" ,
i mean lose all info, not sure why @TheGeneral

Comment: @Felixanius its hard to help you. Its hard to know exactly what you are seeing, what your environment is, all i know is i run your code and it works (as you can see). My gut feeling is you are doing something that you are not showing in your question. Or maybe something else is a miss, but its kind of impossible for us to know unless you really try hard to explain what is happening and the exact code, setup, environment ect

Comment: no much to explain tbh, somehow i get wrong values after deserialize ,
u can check the comment i added, should get the same exception instance @TheGeneral

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your issue.I got the same results as TheGeneral.

Maybe you could customize a `Type` for your `Obj` data as a workaround.

like:

```
publcic class JsonWrapper
    {
        public string ObjType { get; set; }
        public Bean Obj { get; set; }

        public class Bean
        {
            public string ClassName { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
            public string Data { get; set; }
            public string InnerException { get; set; }
             ...
        }
    }
```

then you could get the Message :

```
 var json = "{\"ObjType\":\"System.Exception\",\"Obj\":{\"ClassName\":\"System.Exception\",\"Message\":\"Printer Is Not Connected\",\"Data\":null,\"InnerException\":null,\"HelpURL\":null,\"StackTraceString\":null,\"RemoteStackTraceString\":null,\"RemoteStackIndex\":0,\"ExceptionMethod\":null,\"HResult\":-2146233088,\"Source\":null,\"WatsonBuckets\":null}}\r\n";
 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonWrapper>(json);
 var obj2 = obj.Obj;
 var message = obj2.Message;
```

Comment: the jsonwrapper is used to deal with different types, there's another class with the same fields name and generic to serialize before conver to json string then deserialize to the another JsonWrapper class, whatever this isn't the issue 
there's an issue with xamarin app even if serialized and deserialized an object directly like i mentioned in the comment u can check @Leo Zhu

Answer (score 0):

my issue is somehow i'm not getting the same instance after deserialize the Json string
not sure why [image]

check this please, on console app i get a exception instance with the same message or whatever data in the original instance

Comment: It's weird,i create an Exception as you do above,but i could get the correct Message which i defined before.